# How to execute a raw sql query from LINQ to Entities 4.5?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

### Problem

I need to execute a raw SQL query from LINQ to Entities and retrieve the result.  The query returns the current date/time from the SQL Server instance, and looks like this:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

[Edit]
I'm using a data model that was created database-first.
[/Edit]

### What I've Tried

I've researched this issue on the interwebz and been unable to find a technique to do this.  I was able to learn how to do this using LINQ to SQL, but since I'm not using that, it's of no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres what you are after

```
var time = context.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()").FirstOrDefault();
```

You can read more about raw sql and EF here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: I believe that the sample you'e posted is LINQ to SQL, right?  I want to do something like this using LINQ to Entities.

Comment: this is linq to entities, see the article *Entity Framework allows you to query using LINQ with your entity classes. However, there may be times that you want to run queries using raw SQL directly against the database. This includes calling stored procedures, which can be helpful for Code First models that currently do not support mapping to stored procedures. The techniques shown in this topic apply equally to models created with Code First and the EF Designer.* Also I use this myself its off the top of IDbSet (linq to entities)

Comment: I don't see how to get the object you've named context.  In my code, I have an edmx model, and generate what I've been calling a context like this: `private AppEntities _db = new AppEntities();`, where AppEntities is the name of the data model.  From there, I access data by using LINQ to Entitites, like `var question = (from q in _db.Question select q).SingleOrDefault();`.  How do I get what you're calling `context`?

Comment: @STLDeveloper `_db.Database.Sql.....` Assuming that `AppEntities` is a `DbContext` (which it should be if you are using a recent version of EF). If you are using an old version of EF and have an ObjectContext not a DbContext you can use `_db.ExecuteStoreQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()")...` You should also add the version of EF into your tags and let us know if you are using codefirst or not

Comment: Luke, thank you for the advice.  I've updated my question.  Sorry not to have understood what you were trying to tell me the first time!  I've accepted your answer - thank you for your help!